# Динамически изменяется переменная в процедуре

Tags: python, классы

Я делаю тетрис на питоне и столкнулся с одной проблемой.

Код:

```
import numpy as np
import time
import random
import os

class Tetris:
    def __init__(self):
        self.field = np.array([[0] * 12] + [[7] + [0] * 10 + [7]] * 20 + [[7] * 12])  # поле
        self.Tblock = {0: [1, 1], 1: [0, 0], 2: [0, 2], 3: [0, 1]}  # 1
        self.LbLock = {0: [0, 1], 1: [0, 0], 2: [1, 2], 3: [0, 2]}  # 2
        self.InvLblock = {0: [1, 1], 1: [0, 0], 2: [0, 2], 3: [0, 1]}  # 3
        self.Stick = {0: [1, 1], 1: [0, 0], 2: [0, 2], 3: [0, 1]}  # 4
        self.Zblock = {0: [1, 1], 1: [0, 0], 2: [0, 2], 3: [0, 1]}  # 5
        self.InvZblock = {0: [0, 1], 1: [0, 0], 2: [0, 2], 3: [0, 3]}  # 6
        self.DownCount = 1
        self.shift = 5
        self.nom = 1
        self.check = False
        self.block = []

    def rnd(self):
        if self.nom == 1:
            self.block = self.Tblock
        elif self.nom == 2:
            self.block = self.LbLock
        elif self.nom == 3:
            self.block = self.InvLblock
        elif self.nom == 4:
            self.block = self.Stick
        elif self.nom == 5:
            self.block = self.Zblock
        elif self.nom == 6:
            self.block = self.InvZblock

    def drafter(self):
        checker = False
        nom = self.nom * 10
        place = self.field
        while True:

            self.field = place


            for i in range(4):
                self.field[self.block[i][0] + self.DownCount, self.block[i][1] + self.shift] = nom
            os.system('cls')

            for i in range(4):
                b = self.field[self.block[i][0] + self.DownCount + 1, self.block[i][1] + self.shift]
                if b != nom:
                    if b != 0:
                        checker = True
                        break
            if checker:
                for i in range(4):
                    self.field[self.block[i][0] + self.DownCount, self.block[i][1] + self.shift] = nom / 10
                print(self.field)
                self.DownCount = 1
                break

            self.DownCount += 1

            print(self.field)
            time.sleep(1)

    def game_process(self):
        c = 0
        while True:
            self.rnd()
            self.drafter()

            for i in range(5, 9):
                if self.field[1][i] != 0:
                    c += 1
            if c >= 2:
                break
        print("Game  Over")


if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Tetris()
    game.game_process()
```

Тут `place = self.field` я присваиваю переменной первоначальное состояние поля чтобы обнулить поле и отрисрвать блоки в другом месте `self.field = place`, однако получается так, что переменная `place` меняется вместе с `self.field`. Как можно это поравить?

Answer (score 1):

На подобные вопросы тут много раз отвечали, но раз вы спрашиваете. Тут вы на самом деле копируете не объект, а ссылку на него:

```
place = self.field
```

Переменная `place` теперь указывает на тот же объект, что и `self.field`. Чтобы скопировать объект, нужно прямо так и написать "хочу копию объекта":

```
place = self.field.copy()
```

Теперь это два независимых объекта, которые можно менять, не затрагивая другой объект.

P.S. Обратное когда присваиваение делаете, тоже нужно, конечно, копировать:

```
self.field = place.copy()
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я предполагал, что это так, но 3 дня гулежки ни к чему не привели.

Comment: @Акакиймартенов Почитайте про `value types` и `reference types`. Кстати, даже и `copy` не всегда помогает, для объектов с ещё более вложенной структурой нужно использовать `deepcopy`. В вашем то случае обычной копии достаточно должно быть, у вас просто матрица.

Comment: Хотя на самом деле в питоне практически всё объекты reference type, но в целом правила работы с сущностями и в нём идут из этого разделения.

Comment: Теперь программа выдает ошибку если я делаю так 'self.field = place' , то возникает такая ошибка  ' self.field[self.block[i][0] + self.DownCount, self.block[i][1] + self.shift] = nom
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object does not support item assignment
'

Comment: Во-первых обратно тоже нужно копировать, а не просто присваивать, я дописал это в ответ. Во-вторых, может вы круглые скобки забыли и пишете просто `.copy` без скобок? У меня с вашим кодом ошибок нет.

Answer (score 0):

Сначала нужно импортировать

```
import copy
```

Потом скопировать

```
place = copy.copy(self.field)
```

И в цикле тоже необходимо копировать

```
self.field = copy.copy(place)
```

Comment: Там же `numpy.array` используется, у него есть своя встроенная функция `.copy()`, дополнительная библиотека не нужна.